# How can I setup fiddlercore catch http request/response that without AfterSessionComplete?

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

I want to catch a third-party made application's http/https messages with fiddlercore in C#.
I'm not sure what kind of the connection type is but what I did is

```
        FiddlerApplication.OnReadRequestBuffer += FiddlerApplication_OnReadRequestBuffer;
        FiddlerApplication.OnReadResponseBuffer += FiddlerApplication_OnReadResponseBuffer;
        FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;
        FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, false, true);
```

Then I start the application and setup proxy to fiddler's.
The AfterSessionComplete is called only once. The response code is 200 but responseBody is empty.

However, after that I keep receiving OnReadRequestBuffer and OnReadResponseBuffer. The application does keep connecting with the internet(through fiddler proxy)

In my other project I found any messages goes in and out through fiddler should contain one BeforeRequest, then some OnReadRequestBuffer, then following some OnReadResponseBuffer and finally one AfterSessionComplete.
In my mind this is the model of any single post/get process.

But here what I encountered here is that the session won't complete and request -> response -> another requests -> another response...

So how can I catch every full request and the full response to it?
Is there any callback that gives the sign of a full request or a full response is done?

How can I decrypt https base on the partial buffers that runs in and out that caught by OnReadRequestBuffer/OnReadResponseBuffer?

Edit: OnWebSocketMessage is never triggered. Someone says that this kind of protocol could be COMET. But I find nothing about how to catch COMET messages with fiddler. (And I know nothing about COMET)